# Hessian serialization library for javascript?

Tags: javascript, serialization, deserialization, hessian

I am just getting started with Hessian and have been surprised to discover that there is apparently no library for Hessian functionality (particularly serialization / deserialization) in javascript. I guess I have 2 questions:

1) Is there in fact a decent Hessian library for javascript that I haven't found?

2) If not, is there a good reason why one doesn't exist?

Thanks

Comment: For all who don't know what Hessian is: http://hessian.caucho.com/.

Comment: Which version of the Hessian Spec are you looking for, [v1](http://hessian.caucho.com/doc/hessian-1.0-spec.xtp) or [v2](http://hessian.caucho.com/doc/hessian-ws)?

Answer (score 3):

A bit of self promotion, I've written a Node.js Hessian parser in JavaScript. It is available in [npm](http://npmjs.org/package/hessian) or on [github](https://github.com/bramp/hessian.js).

Currently it only supports decoding hessian data, I've personally not got any need to write the encoder at this point. One thing I was looking for, was some example encoded data that I could use as part of my unit tests. Any suggestions on where I could find some? or do I need to create it myself?

Answer (score 2):

I just write one for RPC calls, similar to ruby-hessian. only available in nodejs. the usage docs is in https://github.com/villadora/node-hessian. Tested for Hessian v2.0 in http://hessian.caucho.com/test/test2.

To install:

```
npm install hessian-proxy
```

Answer (score 1):

According to their [web site](http://hessian.caucho.com/), it doesn't look like there's a JavaScript port out there.

Why one doesn't exist?  Not sure, but it seems that the developer of Hessian seems to advocate Flash/Flex as the client-side implementation platform of choice.  Of course, the web site seems to be a little dated and may have been put together before JavaScript's popularity really took off.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I succeeded on putting the Bram's library to run in browser. It's ugly code, but it's working. Please take a look https://github.com/CarlosUrbina/hessianInBrowser

Edit:
I realized Bram's library supports only decoding the Hessian 1.0 spec. Unfortunately, my app is running on Hessian 2.0, so I needed to write my own library.
https://github.com/CarlosUrbina/Hessian2Javascript

Is AMD ready and proved to work in Chrome 27 and Firefox 21. Altought, you need to be careful with the same domain policy. If you need to call web services in another domain, this may not work that well.

I only implemented the data types I needed, so the encoding part is just encoding integers. The decoder is more robust, and implementing the lacking types shouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 1):

npm install hession.js

https://github.com/node-modules/hessian.js

Hessian Serialization 1.0 and 2.0 written by pure JavaScript. Support all kind of types in Java.